# When water flows over a curved surface, will it reduce the pressure on the curved surface? Is this because of the viscosity of water?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I think it's because water moves on a curved surface with centripetal force. Because the gravity of water provides centripetal force, the pressure of water on the curved surface is reduced. When the velocity of water increases, the pressure of water on the curved surface will be more reduced. When the velocity of water is large enough, it separates from the curved surface, because gravity can no longer provide centripetal force. But some people think that viscosity reduces the pressure of water on curved surfaces. Are they right?
[image]

This surface is a convex surface.

Comment: I think it is wrong to say to say gravity provides a centripetal force. Sure, you have to  take in the normal force of the surface, but think about the case where the slope is either 0 degrees is or 90 degrees. There is no net force pointing toward the "center".

Comment: @AmIAStudent I think gravity has a normal component.

Comment: perhaps you can draw a free body diagram to convince yourself that it is true or not.

Comment: @AmIAStudent Imagine that there must be pressure when water moves on a horizontal plane because of the gravity of the water. When water moves on an inclined plane, does it have no pressure on the inclined plane?

Comment: I agree there is pressure in the water, but pressure is a scalar and has no direction. I was pointing out that the net force from gravity of water and normal force from the surface seems unlikely to produce a centripetal force. Centripetal force means there is a force pointing to the center to which the radius of the curvature is defined.

Comment: @AmIAStudent The pressure of water acts on the surface, which is normal, and the normal force is directed to the center of curvature of the surface. I don't know why it doesn't point to the center of curvature. Can you explain it again? I suggest you give me a picture.

Comment: If $\theta$ is the angle between the z-axis (along which there is gravity), then there is $\rho g\cos\theta$ along the radius. The normal force from the surface balances it out. So there is only tangential acceleration $\rho g \sin\theta$, which may be balanced by pressure gradient along the stream I guess. I really meant this simple picture.

Comment: @AmIAStudent The gravity of water has two components one in the normal direction and the other in the tangent direction. Since water moves along a curve, part of the normal force is used for centripetal force.

Comment: The normal component is canceled by the normal force from the surface. Newton's third law. Now if the water stream were to travel in a curved *pipe*, I'm inclined to agree that there is a centripetal force in that constrained system, from the wall of the pipe. But there is no such constraint, at least according to the drawing.

Comment: @AmIAStudent Your idea is wrong. The container has no lid, but because of gravity, the water in the container also has pressure. It can be said that gravity is also a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this by applying Euler's equation *across* streamlines on the curved flow (ignoring gravity if it's a thin flow):

$$ \frac{dP}{dr} = \rho \frac{V^2}{R}$$

where $R$ is the radius of curvature of the bend, and $V$ is the streamline flow velocity. Clearly, pressure must increase radially outward. However, pressure at the surface is atmospheric; pressure below the surface is therefore below atmospheric (again, ignoring gravity).

Comment: If atmospheric pressure is neglected, centripetal force is provided by the gravity of water.